# Change the value of column based on the another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two arrays.

```
b = np.array([[-2,1,1],[-99,1,0],[-12,0,1],[-100,0,0]])
z = np.array([[0,0,0],[0,1,1],[2,1,0],[-1,0,1]])

print(b)

[[  -2    1    1]
 [ -99    1    0]
 [ -12    0    1]
 [-100    0    0]]

print(z) 

[[ 0  0  0]
 [ 0  1  1]
 [ 2  1  0]
 [-1  0  1]]
```

What I want to change is that the values of first columns(`[-2, -99, -12, -100]`) of the first array(`b`). More particularly, these should be changed based on the second and third columns which are same as the another array's (`z`).

For instance, the first row of `b` (`[  -2    1    1]`) would be changed to (`[ 0  1  1]`) because the second(`1`) and third value(`1`) of first row are same as the second row of `z` (`[0  1  1]`). However, I want to keep the order of rows in `z`. Therefore,

```
# b
[[  -2    1    1]
 [ -99    1    0]
 [ -12    0    1]
 [-100    0    0]]

# would be .. 
[[ 0  1  1]
 [ 2  1  0]
 [ -1  0  1]
 [ 0  0  0]]
```

It seems inevitable to use the loop but I expect there are other ways to implement by the *Numpy style trick*.

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [`np.lexsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html) to get an indirect sort (just a 1-d array with the "sorted indexes") of both `b` and `z` to match the second and third columns, and then use advanced assignment to correctly assign the first column to the respective rows.

try this:

```py
import numpy as np

b = np.array([[-2, 1, 1], [-99, 1, 0], [-12, 0, 1], [-100, 0, 0]])
z = np.array([[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1], [2, 1, 0], [-1, 0, 1]])

b_argsorted = np.lexsort((b[:, 1], b[:, 2]))
z_argsorted = np.lexsort((z[:, 1], z[:, 2]))

b[b_argsorted, 0] = z[z_argsorted, 0]

print(b)
```

Output (same as yours):

```
[[ 0  1  1]
 [ 2  1  0]
 [-1  0  1]
 [ 0  0  0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

you could do :

```py
ix = [np.argmax((z[:,1:] == b_[1:]).all(axis = 1)) for b_ in b]
b[:,0] = z[:,0][ix]
print(b)
```

```py
[[ 0  1  1]
 [ 2  1  0]
 [-1  0  1]
 [ 0  0  0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution for this using for Loops:

```
import numpy as np

b = np.array([[-2,1,1],[-99,1,0],[-12,0,1],[-100,0,0]])
z = np.array([[0,0,0],[0,1,1],[2,1,0],[-1,0,1]])
print(b)
print("="*50)

for row in b:
    for r in z:
        if row[-1] == r[-1] and row[-2] == r[-2]:
            row[0] = r[0]

print(b)
```